# Truncate additional tags from an image URL

Tags: php

I want image urls to be auto embedded when post in post/comment field in a wordpress theme.

I already got this code to work in functions.php:

```
function content_magic($content)
{
    $content = get_the_content();
    $m = preg_match_all('!http://[a-z0-9\-\.\/]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui', $content, $matches);
    if ($m) {
        $links = $matches[0];
        for ($j = 0; $j < $m; $j++) {
            $content = str_replace($links[$j], '<img src="' . $links[$j] . '">', $content);
        }
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'content_magic');
```

BUT: as soon as you post via wordpress iphone app it doesn't work anymore because image posts from the iphone app automatically add the tags **alt="20121108-172156.jpg" class="alignnone size-full" />** at the end after"

how can I truncate the "alt" and "class" tags after the end of the url starting from ?:jpe?g|png|gif" to "/> with the code above?

Comment: Sounds like the iPhone app adds these attributes to the html during it processes it. A solution could be to provide a default value for alt and class in your code, so iPhone wont mess with it then...

Comment: Hm, I think it would be easier to tell the "preg_match_all" above to just cut off all characters after ".jpg/.gif" until "/>" - but I don't know how to do that since I'm REALLY not good at coding...

Comment: I don't think that is the way to go. The source you are processing contains an image url surrounded by excalamtion marks. The img tag and its attributes does no exist in $content. You create it. Give adding default empty values for class and alt a try... `$content=str_replace($links[$j],'<img src="'.$links[$j].'" alt="" />',$content);`